# Should I really write different CSS code for different browsers?

Tags: css

I am new to web development. I was wondering if I should really write different CSS code for different browsers. If I should, any tips for writing and testing my website in different browsers? Also, which browsers should I write different CSS code for? Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is yes, it's needed for stability and consistency between browsers. However, most code compilers like Grunt/Gulp/Webpack etc will have a process for putting the required prefixes in based on the code you're writing. Check your code between Edge, Chrome & Firefox to begin with and that should cover most of your issues. You can also use [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/) to see how well CSS declarations are supported.

Comment: You may want to consider a tool like [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to help with your testing.

Comment: Almost all modern browsers support majority of the CSS rules etc. But rarely you find a bug that is browser specific. In those cases, Yes.. you should write browser specific. You can use a Normalise CSS stylesheet to get the looks alright on all browsers overriding user agent styles beforehand if thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you use autoprefixer then it will do all the different browser stuff for you: https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/

For testing in different browsers you could use something like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write CSS code that targets the largest audience or market. Currently, the most used browser is Google Chrome. If you're more comfortable with another browser such as IE or Safari you can choose to write browser-specific CSS code.
Be sure to check the browser compatibility of the CSS properties you're using on the MDN Web Docs. Cheers!

Comment: Okay then should I show a notification for the user saying "This website only supports (some browser)"?

Comment: That approach gave us a a massive problem back in the 2000s because there were a huge number of websites that only worked with IE6's many foibles, which ultimately held up the progress of the web for a good few years.